# Evaluate expression inside of a string as dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to read string which contains Python expression and try to evaluate them using `ast.literal_eval`.
Expected result should be `dict`. Instead I get `str`.
What am I doing wrong?

### test.txt

```
{prompt : 'prompt1> ' , command : 'cmd1'}
{prompt : 'prompt2> ' , command : 'cmd2'}
{prompt : 'prompt3> ' , command : 'cmd3'}
{prompt : 'prompt4> ' , command : 'cmd4'}
```

### the function

```
def send_commands(commands):
    with open(commands, 'r') as file:
        current_line = ast.literal_eval('"' + next(file).rstrip("\n") + '"')
        for next_line in file:
            next_line = ast.literal_eval('"' + next_line.rstrip("\n") + '"')
            print(current_line)
            print(next_line)
            print("type:", type(current_line), type(next_line))
            current_line = next_line

import ast
commands     = "test.txt"
send_commands(commands)
```

### output

```
{prompt : 'prompt1> ' , command : 'cmd1'}
{prompt : 'prompt2> ' , command : 'cmd2'}
type: <class 'str'> <class 'str'>
{prompt : 'prompt2> ' , command : 'cmd2'}
{prompt : 'prompt3> ' , command : 'cmd3'}
type: <class 'str'> <class 'str'>
{prompt : 'prompt3> ' , command : 'cmd3'}
{prompt : 'prompt4> ' , command : 'cmd4'}
type: <class 'str'> <class 'str'>
```

***Fix: Here is the output after putting quotations around `'prompt` and `command` as suggested bellow. They are `dict` but swapped. Probably because `eval` does some ordering based on hex values of the first character.***

```
{'command': 'cmd1', 'prompt': 'prompt1> '}
{'command': 'cmd2', 'prompt': 'prompt2> '}
type: <class 'dict'> <class 'dict'>
{'command': 'cmd2', 'prompt': 'prompt2> '}
{'command': 'cmd3', 'prompt': 'prompt3> '}
type: <class 'dict'> <class 'dict'>
{'command': 'cmd3', 'prompt': 'prompt3> '}
{'command': 'cmd4', 'prompt': 'prompt4> '}
type: <class 'dict'> <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: Well, see those quotation marks you’re surrounding the input with?

Comment: About `Fix` part: Dictionary is not an ordered collection.

Comment: True, dictionary is not an order structure. If you know for sure that `eval_literal` is not doing any ordering , I'll remove it not to confuse people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the code surround the lines with quote.

You need to surround the `prompt` and `command` with quote, not the whole line.

Comment: It works. That means that keys should always be strings. Shouldn't `eval` be smart to do that by itself?

Comment: @flamenco, No `eval` does not. Don't use `eval` if possible. It can execute abitrary expression.

Comment: Is anything else available to evaluate expressions inside strings? How would you do it?

Comment: @flamenco `eval` is smart enough *not* to do that. Because a reference to a string is a legal key value, there's no reason to assume that `prompt` should be a literal string unless you quote it yourself.